# Ionic 4 Angular Back Button to previous page instead of root?

Tags: angular, routes, back-button, ionic4

I have a little Ionic 4 App with 2 Tabs and 1 Detail Page. 
The Problem I'm facing here is that if I go from Tab2 into Detail Page and from there with `ion-back-button` back it always redirect me to Tab1 instead of Tab2 where I was before.

Here is my example:

Tab2 Html:
Here I have a simple ion-item with a click event:

```html
        <ion-item class="chat-item" (click)='openChat()' >
```

It calls the openChat funtion which works like this:

```js
          openChat() {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/chatdetail/:uid');
          }
```

Now it opens my Chatdetail Page in which I have placed a Back Button to navigate back like this:

```html
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
              <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
           </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>chatdetail</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
```

But when I click this Button it doesn't just "pop" the page like it was in Ionic3 instead it directs me to the root page of my App which is Tab1.

Is there any way of overwriting that back event to go to the page I was before?

Comment: This is fixed by: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.3.0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update:**

Ionic team has fixed this on Ver: [4.3.0](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.3.0)

**Old**

You need to use `defaultHref="/Tab2"` like so:

```
  <ion-back-button defaultHref="/Tab2"></ion-back-button>
```

> The url to navigate back to by default when there is no history.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button

*How to go to the previous page?*

`import { Location } from "@angular/common";`

`constructor(private location: Location) { }`

```
myBackButton(){
  this.location.back();
}
```

Comment: So in fact if I navigate forward I have to track from where I started and pass it to the new page, so I can return back to the old page? Ionic 3 handled this perfect by itself. This is really bad for mobile development with many pages and way to much work compared to ionic 3

Comment: Can you please update your answer with this now: This is fixed by: github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.3.0

Comment: @LukasR. Done that.

Comment: SO basically this does not work "out of the box" anymore? we have to create a function to track where we are?

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Please create a new Question with your use case.

Comment: Man, this worked like charm! Been banging my head for several hours. Cheers.

Comment: Use location.back() will not have animation.

Comment: location.back() not work for IOS

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NavController` for this. It works perfect for me.

---

### Step 1 :

Import NavController in your ***.ts*** file

`import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';`

---

### Step 2 :

Add it to your constructor

`contructor( private navCtrl: NavController ){}`

---

### Step 3 :

Use it in your method

```
openChat() {
    this.navCtrl.back();
}
```

---

### Step 4 :

in your ***.html*** file

`<ion-item class="chat-item" (click)='openChat()' >`

Comment: Still working in 2023. Great help.

Comment: yes @NajamUsSaqib

Answer (score 1):

You should navigate as

```html
<ion-item class="chat-item" [routerLink]="[/chatdetail, 123]" routerDirection="forward">
```

`routerDirection="forward"`
stacks detailPage on Tabs pages and you will be navigated back to right tab page

:}

Answer (score 1):

by using nav-control we can go back like following

add public navCtrl: NavController in the constructor

```
back(){
  let animations:AnimationOptions={
    animated: true,
    animationDirection: "back"
  }
  this.navCtrl.back(animations)
}
```