# Ionic 4 routing caching / history preservation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

Is there any way to preserve the history of your actions on the app?

Here is a basic flow of my app:

1. `search.page.ts`
   find some records
2. `result.page.ts`
   go to record view
3. `case.page.ts`
   from record view navigate to a case this record is linked to
4. `result.page.ts`
   from case click on record view again

When I click `<ion-back-button />` I expect to return to `case.page.ts`.

However, what happens is I am redirected straight to `search.page.ts`.

It seems that when I navigate from `case.page.ts` the history of my clicks isn't building up but reverses because the page I am intending to go to has already been visited.

Question is how do I deal with this situation? Because my typical user definitely wants to return to case in this example.

Edit: I created a quick POC that tricks router into achieving my expected behaviour, but I don't like it, it was just a quick test, basically adding some random hash to the ID of the result, which tricks router into building a full path:

case.page.html

```
// link to result from case page
[routerLink]="['/record-view/', recordId+'3SRzrMbhcQGpA']"
```

result.page.html

```
// remove hash from the id passed from case
this.recordId = paramMap.get('recordId').replace("3SRzrMbhcQGpA", "");
```

Comment: maybe [this article](https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/) could help you

Comment: I still would try adding [replaceUrl]="true" to your link see if that works

Comment: This seems to be a similar case as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892266/ionic-4-angular-back-button-to-previous-page-instead-of-root). Diff is the post is using tabs, however Location should help with the routing.