# IONIC v7 ion-back-button wrong redirect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have different pages across the app that require a "back-button" on the top that when clicked it navitages to the page that was right before that.

Lets take the page "Appointment" for example, it's navigated to from different pages across all the app.
using this method:

```
 <ion-card routerLink="appointment" [queryParams]="{ ... }"></>
```

Now this page also has links to his "father" pages,
Routes of one of the "father" pages:

```
Client page:
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ClientPage
      },
      {
        path: 'appointment',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../home/appointment/appointment.module').then( m => m.AppointmentPageModule)
      },
    ];
```

Given that i use `loadChildren: () => import...` i cant import in the same way the ClientPage to Appointment.
So i use this inside Appointment.ts:

```
this.router.navigate(['/tabs/my-client/client'], { queryParams });
```

Now using this

```
<ion-back-button text="go back"></ion-back-button>
```

will cause some problems

- if i use this.router.navigate the ion-back-button is not shown at all cuz there is no navigation history
- if i put defaultHref="" then when i press it, it wont go back to the page that was before

I found a solution that is using a custon button like that:

```
<ion-button (click)="goBack()">go back</ion-button>

import {Location} from '@angular/common';
goBack(){
 this.location.back();
}
```

But then i won't have the graphic/visual generated by the native ion-back-button....

Any help?

Already check other questions like: [Ionic 4 Angular Back Button to previous page instead of root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892266/ionic-4-angular-back-button-to-previous-page-instead-of-root)
No fixes

Comment: did you try using NavController? that should work.

Comment: You should use: answer given in the URl you posted with navController. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70052595/5909026

Comment: why are you adding `defaultHref=""` with empty value? 'defaultHref' is only set to be read in case the page was accessed directly without navigation so it returns the user back to a default page, so add add it with any value, and in case you need to do a custom back button, then you can also use navController in the click function, and set the Navigation Direction to forward or back or root and this will still add the default routing animation..